# Adding a manager node in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I started docker in swarm mode by:

```
$ docker swarm init
Swarm initialized: current node (4szigol8wugf0m1bqhxei9bvh) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4oy3q8mzepcjrrms17uwtp0pp0rc1ttkztpq2v97r0detnvokl-2uvc24bcy2gnrc4kmy9ndlsum 192.168.65.3:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.
```

I followed the instruction from the prompt to add a manager to this swarm:

```
$ docker swarm join-token manager
To add a manager to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4oy3q8mzepcjrrms17uwtp0pp0rc1ttkztpq2v97r0detnvokl-2xo3hfhghuzsitx1uybqxvyav 192.168.65.3:2377
```

As you can see above, it shows me another command to add the manager. So I again run as instructed:

```
$ docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4oy3q8mzepcjrrms17uwtp0pp0rc1ttkztpq2v97r0detnvokl-2xo3hfhghuzsitx1uybqxvyav 192.168.65.3:2377
Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
```

Then I encounter this error message above, I again followed the instruction to leave the swarm:

```
$ docker swarm leave
Error response from daemon: You are attempting to leave the swarm on a node that is participating as a manager. Removing the last manager erases all current state of the swarm. Use `--force` to ignore this message.
```

But leaving the swarm is also not allowed.

I have two questions:

1. Why adding a manager to swarm takes two commands? one is `docker swarm join-token manager`, 2nd one is `docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4oy3q8mzepcjrrms17uwtp0pp0rc1ttkztpq2v97r0detnvokl-2xo3hfhghuzsitx1uybqxvyav 192.168.65.3:2377`, underneath, I actually understand more the 2nd command which uses token to add manager, what's the point of having the first add manager command then?
2. I understand the instruction, but what could I do if I can't adding manager in current node because the node is already in a swarm, neither can I leave the swarm because it is a leader manager node?  No way for me to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. The first command is not adding the manager, it's just allowing you to retrieve the token in order to be able to join. The worker and managers use different tokens and the default one it shows is for the worker.
2. If the node is currently a manager in the Swarm you want, what's the problem? If it's a manager in another Swarm (which you don't care about or whatever) then just leave it with `--force` (like the instructions say) and then use the above command to join the Swarm you want?

Comment: I just want to know how can I switch to the 2nd node and join the swarm as manager when the error message says I am already in a node.  I also tried to use `--force` flag to leave the first node, then join with the command `docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4oy3q8mze0rc1ttkztpq2v97r0detnvokl-2xo3hfhghuzsitx1uybqxvyav 192.168.65.3:2377`, I got new error `Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 192.168.65.3:2377: connect: connection refused"`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.